# Rails two-way self-referential has_many :through -- controller setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, a user can subscribe to other users. One should be able to get a user's subscriptions and subscribers from a user instance.

Right now, I have a `User` model and a `Subscription` model. `Subscription` is the join model (joining `User` to `User`) in a two-way self-referential `has_many :through` relationship.

Subscription:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :to_user, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :subscriptions_as_subscriber, :foreign_key => 'from_user_id', :class_name => 'Subscription', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subscriptions_as_subscription, :foreign_key => 'to_user_id', :class_name => 'Subscription', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions_as_subscription, :source => :from_user
  has_many :subscriptions, :through => :subscriptions_as_subscriber, :source => :to_user
  ...
end
```

First question: Would I be better served by a different setup?

Second question: How might I create controller(s) to create and destroy Subscriptions and to access a User's subscriptions and subscribers?

Right now, I have a `SubscriptionsController` with `create` and `destroy` actions, and `subscriptions` and `subscribers` actions in my `UsersController`. However, I'm wondering if there isn't a better (more RESTful?) way to do this. Accesssing a user's subscriptions and subscribers through the `index` action on `SubscriptionsController`, perhaps?

Comment: A has_and_belongs_to_many relation should would be best imo. HABTM followers, and HABTM following.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [awesome_nested_set](http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) from collective_idea.  It is a breeze to implement and should give you the functionality you are looking for.

Here is a post with some details on implementation that you can borrow from:  http://www.justinball.com/2009/01/18/heirarchies-trees-jquery-prototype-scriptaculous-and-acts_as_nested_set/

UPDATE:

I would see this setup as a tree:

```
Subscriber
 + subscription
   + subscription
     + subscription
   + subscription
   + subscription
 + subscription
```

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. Unfortunately, I don't think this will help me. This looks to be useful for building trees (say, for hierarchical comments), but not for my scenario. Maybe I'm missing something.