# How to query the inverse of a self-referential "has_many :through" relationship in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, relationships

Our Rails application uses a self-referential `has_many` relationship on our `User` class to track followings. This works to find `followed_users`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followed_users, through: :followings
end

class Following < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :followed_user, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I was specifically asked to create a `has_many :follower_users`. I cannot seem to be able to generate the correct query to get the inverse. The closest I have come is an instance method which works

```
def followers
  User.includes(:followings).where followings: { followed_user_id: id }
end
```

but I was told to query the inverse through a `has_many`, not an instance method.

Is this possible?

Comment: See if this tutorial can provide some insight into what you are trying to achieve: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it after I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098817) post:

```
has_many :followers, foreign_key: :followed_user_id, class_name: 'Following'
has_many :follower_users, through: :followers, source: :user
```

I had a misunderstanding in how I first had to define the join relationship, then (in effect) follow that join through to the `User` class. It was my faulty assumption that I could directly describe the join and through in a single statement.